# Is it possible to set up the Main Branch name automatically?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I use sonar-runner (2.8) to launch analysis in Jenkins job.
The Sonar Branch plugin is installed on SonarQube 6.7.1 server that I use.

Regardless of what values I put in params:

sonar.projectKey

sonar.projectName

sonar.branch.name   #from branch plugin

sonar.branch.target  #from branch plugin

I cannot set up the Main branch name. It's always called the "master" which is the default name for Main branch. I also played with the regex responsible for detecting long-live branches.

I can change the branch name of the Main branch by hand on the SonarQube server side (via UI). I'd like to set it up on the parameters side (before the analysis is launched) to avoid manual work.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

The support for branches is part of the SonarQube Developer Edition, which is a commercial package. You will not be able to change the name of the default name if you haven't purchased a license for it.

If you did purchase a license, then you can change the name of the default branch in the "Administration > Branches and Pull Requests" page. You can read more about support for branches on the [documentation page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Branch+Plugin).

Comment: Regarding edition we've got: Edition: Data Center Edition; Type TEST; Expiration December 13, 2018. Regarding your reply: I know we've got Branch plugin installed (1.0 (build 507)installed). I also know that I can change the branch name on the server side (I can do it from Project page hitting in Administration->Branches). My question in generl was about - Can I do it not by hand?  One of your Colleagues (Teryk) replied to me already (Thanks!) that I need to use REST API. So this is more suitable for me: https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/project_branches

Comment: As you've got a Data Center Edition license, this means that you are a SonarSource customer. In this case, you have a access to SonarSource support  and this is the best way for you to get helped. You should get in touch with them.